# Nested / Compounded roles: apply multiple roles to overlapping text

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In my `custom.css` file I have,

```
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.red {
    color:red;
}
```

And in my `_.rst` file,

```
.. role:: bold

.. role:: red
```

But if I try to nest/compound them, only the outermost role takes effect, e.g.

---

``` :bold:`:red:`This is only bold`` ```

**This is only bold**

---

Is there a way to combine these effects without defining a new (combined) role?

Comment: Roles cannot be nested is my finding. Is that your finding as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a custom css class directive:

```
.. cssclass:: boldred

  bold red text
```

and update the css to format the boldred class

Answer (score -2):

Roles are defined that the can not be nested.

Neither HTML nor LaTeX, as backends, support overlapping of styles.

Comment: In latex it's standard to next styles, `\textbf{This is a bold \textit{and italic} sentence}` works just fine.

Comment: You you can meet them, but for LaTeX I wrote you can't overlap them.