# Sphinx add code formatting to :ref:

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to add code formatting to a reference like this:

```
:ref:`__slots__ <python:slots>`
```

My `intersphinx_mapping` defines `python` like this:

```
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'python': ('https://docs.python.org/3', None),
}
```

so the link is to https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots (`slots` is defined in the `std:label` section of `https://docs.python.org/3/objects.inv`)

My goal is to format the rendered link in the style of `:py:attr:` or similar rather than the default text style with which `:ref:` renders.

None of the following options work:

- ```` ... ``:ref:`__slots__ <python:slots>``` ... ```` yeilds output like

  > ... `` :ref:`__slots__ <python:slots>` `` ...
- ``` ... ``:ref:`__slots__ <python:slots>` `` ... ``` yeilds output like

  > ... [__slots__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) ...
- ```` ... :ref:```__slots__`` <python:slots>` ... ```` yeilds output like

  > ... :ref:[``](http://#id1)[`__slots__``](http://#id1) <python:slots>` ...

  There are two separate internal links to `#id1` in this case.
- ``` ... :ref:` ``__slots__`` <python:slots>` ... ``` yeilds output like

  > ... :ref:` [``](http://#id1)__slots__`` <python:slots>` ...

Relpacing ``` ``...`` ``` with `` :code:`...` `` or `` :literal:`...` `` either inside or outside the `:ref:` does not help any either. In fact, it appears that nested roles are not allowed at all.

I would like to have an inline role that results in something that renders with a code style and a link, like

> ... [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) ...

How do I get the basic `:ref:` (or equivalent) to appear with the code-style formatting used by `:py:attr:`?

I am using Sphinx 1.6.3 with Python 3.6.2 in an Anaconda environment.

Inverse question is here: [Sphinx remove code formatting from custom code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45741326/2988730)

A tangentially relevant question: [Nested / Compounded roles: apply multiple roles to overlapping text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43162240/2988730)

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you want. First, do you want this inline and not in a `code-block`? Second, do you want the rendered output to be linked to the Python docs for slots? Finally, do you want to apply a style to the rendered output?

Comment: @StevePiercy. Apologies for the confusion. 1) I would like the `:ref:` (or equivalent) to be inline, as it currently is. 2) I would like the output to be linked to the python docs with label `slots`. 3) I would like the output to be rendered in code font, even though `:ref:` is not. Preferably with the style of `:py:attr:` for this case. If that means applying a style to it, I would be happy to do so.

Comment: I have updated the info above into the question.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. See my answer to your inverse question.

Comment: Could I somehow define a custom role based on `ref` that just adds the same formatting as `:py:attr:`?

Comment: I suppose it is possible, but it sounds like more work than necessary. Personally I would write a post-processor to do a simple find-and-replace on the HTML output.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of a PR to Sphinx itself. That might be even more pointless, so I may end up writing an extension.

Comment: ``:any:`__slots__ <python:slots>` `` works for me (http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#role-any)

Comment: @mzjn. Works for me too. Could you turn that into an answer? In particular, I am curious how to turn that into a more specific role using the info in http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#role-any.

Comment: @mzjn It's odd and ironic that such a great documentation tool is so poorly documented at times.

Comment: Why do you need a more specific role? Isn't `any` good enough? The Python domain has several specific roles, btw: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects

Comment: @mzjn. It will have to do. I was more interested in which role it ended up actually becoming, but the HTML markup showed that it's style class was "any" in addition to a couple of other boilerplate ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`:any:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/referencing.html#role-any) role does what you want:

```
:any:`__slots__ <python:slots>`
```

This is a "convenience role" that looks for cross-reference targets in the current domain as well as targets that work with `:ref:`.

The Python domain has several [specific cross-reference roles](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/domains/python.html#cross-referencing-python-objects), for different types of objects.

Comment: This definitely works, but I don't understand why. I went through every python-specific cross-reference role and none of them worked. Neither does `doc` or `option`. The only thing that works is `ref`, so `any` must be an alias to that, except it magically renders as a code snippet instead of `ref`'s plain text.

Comment: There is a regular `.. _slots:` cross-reference label in the RST source, so it is not strange that ``:ref:`slots` `` works. (`:doc:` and `:option:` are different kinds of cross-references that I would not expect to work). Somehow `:any:` results in code formatting on the link (but I cannot really explain why).